# Copy data from one object to another

Tags: c#

Hey
I want to copy data from one entity to another.
I have something like this :

```
  MyEntity newEntity = new Entity()
  newEntity.Property1 = oldEntity.Property1 ....
```

Is there easier way to do this? I have many properties and I would like to write something like `newEntity = oldEntity`, but this is impossible because of primary key duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use code like this:

```
EntityObject newObject = oldObject;

context.Detach(newObject);
newObject.Id = 0;

context.Entity.AddObject(newObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually what I do in this situation is write a constructor which takes a parameter of the same type (would be called a copy constructor in C++), so you could end up with something like this:

```
// Constructor
MyEntity(MyEntity other)
{
    this.Property1 = other.Property1;
    this.Property2 = other.Property2;
    // etc.
}
```

Then this can be called as follows:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(oldEntity);
```

This also encapsulates the property copying behaviour so that if you add a new property to your class you only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another ASP.NET Futures have ModelCopier helper class.

```
ModelCopier.CopyModel(from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its good to add a Cloning Constructor to the class, but if You want something faster then
loop through Type.GetFields() and use FieldInfo to set value from obj1 to obj2. Just be careful with referenced fields, then you have to do it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method, and its all ok!

```
private static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object destination)
{
    var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (var destProperty in destProperties)
        {
            if (destProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name &&
        destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
            {
                destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(
                    source, new object[] { }), new object[] { });

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nadeem_MK answer also works... just i added a CanWrite flag to handle Readonly properties. Sorry couldnt comment on his answer, as i dont have enough repuatation points.

```
 private static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object destination)
        {
            var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                foreach (var destProperty in destProperties)
                {
                    if (destProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name &&
                destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
                    {
                        if(destProperty.CanWrite)
                        { 
                          destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(
                                source, new object[] { }), new object[] { });
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```